# How to change the position of a label based on how big an image is

Tags: xcode, swift

My image changes size and I want to know how to keep a label in the same spot on the image no matter the size. I want to keep the label inside of a speech bubble, is there a way to put constraints on it to do this, or is there another way? I'm working in Xcode.

Comment: Can you post some code where you are having the problem? Also by "Xcode" do you mean that you are using "Storyboard"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving constant position values, derive the required position using height and width of the image using mathematical calculation.

Example:
Let's say the image size is 400x400 and you want a label at bottom right

You can derive it as

```
X=width-width*0.75
Y=height-height*0.8
```

Now even if the height and width varies, the label will be in same location